# How to trap errors in DLL

Tags: c++, dll, exception

We have a .NET program that calls major functionality in unmanaged C++.  I have a global exception catcher on the .NET side to catch any unhandled errors, but errors such as access violations in the unmanaged C++ DLLs can bring the program down without any logging.  What is the best way to add "global" exception catcher in a DLL?  Can I do this in DllMain?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/EHa` exception handling flag, which will cause your C++ `catch (...)` to also catch structured exceptions, i.e. access violations. The downside of this is that you can't see what the exception was.

Alternatively, you can use a structed exception handler, `__try { } __except(FILTER) { }`, to handle structured exceptions. This allows you to output what type of exception was caught. However, there are limitations on what you can do in a function with a `__try`, such as no C++ exception handling or objects with destructors.

You can, however, get around the `__try` limitation by just calling a function containing the C++ exception handling and original code.

```
void main() {
  __try {
    Foo();
  }
  __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
    // Log some error regarding the structured exception
  }
  return 0;
}

void Foo() {
  try {
    SomeCPPObject bar(1,2);
    DoSomeStuff();
  }
  catch (const std::exception&) {
    // Log the C++ exception
  }
}
```

Be careful, however, as you usually should not continue execution after a structured exception has been raised, as the state of your program could be completely destroyed. It's best to only use this type of exception handling to log an error before exiting.

Comment: Beware! Mixing SEH and C++ exceptions in an application is not permitted. I'm having difficulty finding the MSDN page which states this at length, but in the meantime here is a link: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x057540h.aspx). See the line just before "See Also" which states: "Do not mix the error handling mechanisms[...]"

Comment: There is a bit more information here: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w0chfbk.aspx)

Comment: Your example shows a main routine, but the main section is managed.  I'm calling unmanaged DLLs through P/Invoke and they're the ones that cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

The CLR cannot trap any hardware exceptions that are raised in threads started by the native code.  The only way to do so is by using SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(), the callback you register is called by Windows before it is about to tear down the process.

Using this in a program that also has managed code is filled with traps and pitfalls.  The CLR uses it too, it has to in order to generate exceptions like NullReferenceException and DivideByZeroException.  You have to be very careful to not break that.  Doing something like calling GetThreadId() and only filter exceptions of threads that you know are native ones is important.  Next thing you'd do is, say, use MiniDumpWriteDump() to generate a minidump so that you can debug the crash.